# How to traverse html files and string replace matching results

Tags: php, html, regex, macros, sublimetext

I have a website that's been set up rather poorly (2000+ page files that has code copy/pasted for header+footer sections instead of setting up includes() for external files.)

I was wondering if there was a way I could write some sort of script or macro or something that will go through each file, find a specific snippet that starts with (for example)  and ends with , and just deletes that specific section of code.

I don't have any experience with writing macros or anything else like this so if there's a program that exists or an add-on in sublime or something like that, It would be amazing if someone could point me in that direction. Otherwise, how should I get started in creating something that can do this for me?

Thanks for your help! Please let me know if I can answer any questions to clarify this.

Comment: Yes. It's possible. Yes, there are programs for it. No, we're not going to find them for you, or write the scripts for you.

Comment: Yes.  But this is an extremely broad question.

Comment: @MarcB  Well thank you for letting me know. I wasn't intending on asking anyone to write anything for me - more like I don't know where to get started on learning how to do it myself, so I'd like a nudge in the right direction. 

And if anyone else happens to know the name (or the type-name?) of a program off-hand, I'd appreciate it. You don't have to jump through hoops for me - I just wanted some guidance from someone who knew about this sort of stuff.

Comment: @johnny - how can clarify my intent so that it can be better answered?

Comment: You have to put something you've tried.  That's my first suggestion.  SO isn't not a forum, so you can't ask like you might be used to.  You have to show a specific problem, show the code, maybe what you've tried.

Comment: If you want to start your quest, look for a language or maybe html parsers, regular expressions, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime text 2 or Sublime text 3 supports regex.
They also have features where you can 'find & replace'

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I could use regex with find and replace but it looks like this will solve my problem pretty easily once I brush up on my regex. Your help was much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If the website is hosted on a linux server you can look into sed .  It is extremely powerful and you can have it search recursively on a directory if you pair it with a find command.